# Programmatically control what SSL cert Tomcat presents

Tags: api, tomcat, ssl, certificate

Is it possible to programmatically control the certificate that Tomcat presents during SSL negotiation?  I have a certificate in a non-JKS format, and currently I'm exporting it to PKCS#12 to have it loaded by Tomcat.

I'd like to be able to update the certificate presented while Tomcat is running as well, but this would require a re-export and restart, which I'm hoping to avoid.

Does anyone know if there are any programmatic ties into Tomcat that I could use to load/override/update a custom certificate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think, certificate hot-swap is not possible with full Tomcat, it won't allow your webapp's code to access container configuration through API. But you can do it, if you run Tomcat in [embedded mode](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Embedded.html). You need to remove old HTTP connector from container, create and initialize new connector with different certificate and add it to container.

In Tomcat 6 it would be look like this:

```
// your startup code
Embedded embedded = new Embedded();
// setup context, host, executor etc.
// ...
// your reload certificate API call
Connector con = createAndInitMyNewConnector();
embedded.removeConnector(oldCon);
embedded.addConnector(con);
```

I haven't tried it myself, but it should work.